# How to download pdf generated with rmarkdown via HTTP using OpenCPU

Tags: r, angular, http, r-markdown, opencpu

I'm trying to download a pdf that I've created in a R backend using rmarkdown, but I'm not sure how to retrieve it back via HTTP, if that's even possible. I'm using Angular6 in the front-end and I'm just using basic GET/POST methods to communicate with my backend.

Here is some code related to this question:

Backend code (R):

`EXPORT <- function(results){
  library(rmarkdown)
  library(knitr)
  rmarkdown::render("genepanel.Rmd", output_format = "pdf_document", params = list(results = results))
}`

Front-end code (Angular TypeScript):

`this.http.post(environment.API + '/R/EXPORT/json', results)
    .subscribe(result => console.log(result));`

I don't get any HTTP error when calling the service and the pdf is generated if I manually run the code in the server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the API without the `/json` postfix. You will see an index generated resources and the pdf file should be in there.

Your client should check the `Location` response header from the POST request to `/R/EXPORT` which will contain the location of the session, and you can get the pdf from there.